# Representing limit as a Riemann Sum

Tags: integration, limits, riemann-sum

I need to solve for $a$ in the following: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1^a+2^a+3^a+\cdots +n^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}\left[(na+1)+(na+2)+\cdots (na+n)\right]}=\dfrac{1}{60}$$

**My Attempt**:

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a+\frac{k}{n})\cdot\frac{1}{n}}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}\int_{0}^{1}(a+x)\mathrm dx}\\ &=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{a+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}}\end{aligned}$$

I'm not sure how to proceed. Any hints and mistake pointers are appreciated. The answers provided in the answer key are $7$ and $-17/2$. Thanks

Comment: Hint: What's appear in the limit is approximately the ratio of two Riemann sums (at least when $a > 0$)

$$\frac{(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)^a}{n\sum_{k=1}^n (a + \frac{k}{n})} = \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)^a}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (a + \frac{k}{n})}$$

Comment: @Paras: Do you mean $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a+\frac{k}{n})\cdot{n}$ instead of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a+\frac{k}{n})\cdot\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem. It's the experience that makes you think that way. Many thanks @achillehui :)

Comment: Yes that's a silly mistake on my part @Larry Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: Hmm... the answer key is wrong, $a$ cannot be $-\frac{17}{2}$ as what's in the limit diverges when $a < -1$.

Comment: @achillehui Could you tell me how to rewrite the expression in the numerator as an integral? Do I have to integrate wrt $x+1$? An insight into this would be really helpful. :)

Comment: $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)^a$ is the [left Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Left_Riemann_sum) of $\int_0^1 x^a dx$ for the partition of $[0,1]$ into $n+1$ sub-intervals of length $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: @achillehui I somewhat get it. Thanks a lot for taking part in the discussion and clarifying. :)

Comment: @achille hui: Why does the limit diverge when $a<-1$? I thought the answer key is right.

Comment: @Larry When $a < -1$, $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)^a > \frac{1}{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^a = (n+1)^{|a+1|}$ and RHS diverges.

Comment: @achille hui: Why is here the absolute bracket around $a+1$? I mean $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)^a = \int_{0}^{1}x^adx$, so I still don't see how it diverges.

Comment: @Larry when $a < 0$, the function $x^a$ blows up at $x = 0$, it is no longer Riemann intergrable. For $a \in (-1,0)$, one can still prove the limit of LHS equal to RHS $= \frac{1}{a+1}$. When $a < -1$, the RHS is no longer Lebesgue integrable. Another way to look at it is when $a < -1$, $\frac{1}{a+1} < 0$. It is impossible for LHS, a non-negative sequence, converges to a negative number..

Comment: You can use Cesaro-Stolz to show that $\dfrac{1^a+2^a+\dots+n^a}{n^{a+1}}\to\frac{1}{a+1}$ if $a>-1$ and then your problem reduces to $$\frac{1}{(a+1)(a+(1/2))}=\frac{1}{60}$$